# Why -16 reputation in my Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, reputation

This morning I logged into my Stack Overflow account and then it displayed my account reputation like this:

> [image: Original reputation image]

But after some time I lost 16 reputation (see below). Why? I don't know.

> [image]

Comment: In you [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1197031/zala-janaksinh?tab=reputation) select `show removed posts` (at bottom) check box. It will show you removed posts.

Comment: @hims056 i can't find this

Comment: You mean there is not check box like `show removed posts`?

Comment: @hims056 why duplicate? my question is why minus?and i also can't see this?

Comment: I didn't close your question. And it seem the same reason to me. (suggested edits removed posts)

Comment: @hims056 yes brother i got my answer thanks?

Comment: @Arjan thanks brother...